# How to transform genotypes into T/F -1/0/1 format using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a very large dataset that I would like to transform from genotypes to a coded format. The genotypes should be represented as follows:

```
A A -> -1
A B -> 0
B B -> 1
```

I have thought about this using awk but I cannot seem to get a working solution that can read two columns and output a single code in place of the genotypes. The input file looks like this:

```
AnimalID    Locus       Allele1     Allele2
1       1       A       B
1       2       A       A
1       3       B       B
2       1       B       A
2       2       B       A
2       3       A       A
```

And should be coded to an output file to look like this:

```
AnimalID Locus1 Locus2 Locus3
1 0 -1 1
2 0 0 -1
```

I am assuming this can be done using boolean T/F? Any suggestions would be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: As asked, the question is too broad. Please try to come up with an implementation, and come back with specific problems you are having.

Comment: For smaller implementations I have used awk to combine columns 3 and 4 in a new file. Then I used 3 different iterations of awk to search for AA, AB, and BB and replace with the respective codes. Then I transposed the file and replaced the headings by hand. I was hoping someone had a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't think the question is too broad. It's simple to take the combination of columns and search for strings and replace with the code. What I'm asking for is a more elegant solution using something such as boolean combinations. Some simple direction would be nice rather than passing questions off as "too broad come back later".

Comment: That will vary. In reality it will be up to 50,000 loci.

Comment: No, the number of loci per animal id is not limited to three. It can be any number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started:

I have stored the mapping in `BEGIN` block. If the locus is missing for a particular ID, this will just print blank for that. You didnt specify what B A would mean, so I took the liberty of mapping it to 0 based on your output.

```
awk '
BEGIN { 
    map["A","A"] = -1;
    map["A","B"] =  0;
    map["B","B"] =  1;
    map["B","A"] =  0;
}
NR>1 {
    idCount = (idCount<$1) ? $1 : idCount;
    locusCount = (locusCount<$2) ? $2 : locusCount
    code[$1,$2] = map[$3,$4]
}
END {
    printf "%s ", "AnimalID"; 
    for(cnt=1; cnt<=locusCount; cnt++) { 
        printf "%s%s", "Locus" cnt, ((cnt==locusCount) ? "\n" : " ")
    }
    for(cnt=1; cnt<=idCount; cnt++) {
        printf "%s\t", cnt; 
        for(locus=1; locus<=locusCount; locus++) { 
            printf "%s%s", code[cnt,locus], ((locus==locusCount) ? "\n" : "\t")
        }
    }
}' inputFile
```

#### Output:

```
AnimalID Locus1 Locus2 Locus3
1       0       -1        1
2       0        0       -1
```

Comment: This looks like a good method to me. I will test it on some data files and let you know.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the downvote by mistake, must have been using my phone browser!